# Is there an idiom for playing games with the heart?

Tags: idiom-requests

The pop band Backstreet Boys has this song [Quit Playing Games (With My Heart)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ug88HO2mg44). I wonder what idiom can describe the phrase "play games with someone's heart"? Apparently the phrase "playing games with the heart" sounds perfectly good, but I wonder if there is any other phrase to convey the same meaning. [Googling the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNRfbzPDZZkx6D_gwIaRk5ju8YOxzw%3A1577690228304&ei=dKQJXqaVEo_b9QPdvZbQCQ&q=play+games+with+heart&oq=play+games+with+heart&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i10i30j0i30j0i8i30l8.6343.6952..7273...0.0..0.191.547.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i8i67j0i22i30.-ZgzviwFJZM&ved=0ahUKEwimn_6M6tzmAhWPbX0KHd2eBZoQ4dUDCAo&uact=5), it seems that there is no dictionary acknowledgement of it. The closest idiom could I get is [play one's heart out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+your+heart+out), but it's about being enthusiastic and devoted when playing something (sports, game, instrument).

The idiom should describe the **intention** to gain someone's confidence, only to betray it.

Comment: “Playing games with the heart” *is* the idiom.

Comment: Is there some reason why the phrase "playing games with my heart" isn't adequate? Are you perhaps looking for an idiom that would apply to non-romantic relationships?

Comment: @Lawrence I'm unable to find it in any idiom dictionary

Comment: @nnnnnn well, initially I just want to know if there are any other options or not. But the goal may expand to include an idiom that would apply to non-romantic relationships as you suggest

Comment: Unless you’re reading the statement literally, it’s idiomatic and quite widely understood.

Comment: "Toying with my heart" would be a bit more idiomatic, but there are likely hundreds of ways to express this.

Comment: [The Backstreet Boys](https://www.metrolyrics.com/quit-playing-games-with-my-heart-lyrics-backstreet-boys.html) have written 'Quit playing games with my heart.' Earlier,  [Ronnie Dunlop](https://www.amazon.com/Would-Lifetime-Explain-Ronnie-Dunlop/dp/B005HFSEMO) recorded 'Don't Play Games with my Heart'. [Farlex Idioms Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+games+with+someone) has **play games** [with ...]: _deal with someone or something in a way that lacks due seriousness or respect or deviates from the truth_.

Comment: Your title is ambiguous.  "I play the game with heart" ... means I play the game enthusiastically.  "You play games with my heart" means you toy with my romantic feelings for you.

Comment: Can I combine two idioms? *Rock your world* to *pull the rug from under*

Comment: @Jalene Your comment appears to ask a new question, and is therefor out of place here.

Answer (score -4):

> **rock your world to pull the rug from under**
>
> *-rock someone's world* :
>   to be something that someone likes very much.
>
> *-pull the rug (out) from under (someone)* :
>   To suddenly or unexpectedly remove or rescind support, help, or assistance from someone; to abruptly leave someone in a problematic or difficult situation.

Source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rock%20someone's%20world) [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+the+rug+out)

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?  Your answer needs some explanation - not merely a quote from a dictionary!